# python for loop giving error 'list' object is not callable

Tags: python, for-loop

I have the following piece of python code, which is supposed to access a JSON file stored in an s3 bucket, extract the organisations for each JSON object and then place them in a list. There is a `for` loop then which should go through the list and apply the organisation name to the ending `/bitgear/IO-Air` to create the appropriate IoT topic.

```
for uuid_index, uuid in enumerate(uuid_list):
    s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
    client = boto3.client('s3')
    bucket = '3deo-sensor-data'
    key = 'simulated/config/IoT-sim-config.json'
    obj = s3.Object(bucket, key)
    data = obj.get()['Body'].read().decode('utf-8')
    json_data = json.loads(data)
    dframe = pd.DataFrame(json_data, columns= ['organisation'])
    org = dframe.values.tolist()
    
for orgs in org():
    TOPIC = org[orgs] + '/bitgear/IO-Air'
```

However, I am getting the error `'list' object is not callable`

Here is a snippet of how the JSON file looks:

```
[    
    {
        "uuid": "1597c163-6fbf-4f46-8ff6-1e9eb4f07e34",
        "organisation": "port_36",
        "device_vendor": "bitgear",
        "device_type": "IO-Air",
        "client_id": "AQ_2"
    },
    {
        "uuid": "cde2107e-8736-47de-9e87-2033c3063589",
        "organisation": "hchjffsd2immvavb7jiqtedp",
        "device_vendor": "bitgear",
        "device_type": "IO-Air",
        "client_id": "IoT_Sim_1"
    }
]
```

Can anyone advise how to best form my desired IoT topic using the organisation name?

Comment: This is simply because you use `org()`, org is a list, which is not callable. Therefore you cannot use `()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use pandas for this, `json.loads()` deserialises a string to a Python object. Therefore the json loaded in becomes a list of dictionaries, so you can use:

```py
import json 

topics = []
for uuid_index, uuid in enumerate(uuid_list):
    s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
    client = boto3.client('s3')
    bucket = '3deo-sensor-data'
    key = 'simulated/config/IoT-sim-config.json'
    obj = s3.Object(bucket, key)
    data = obj.get()['Body'].read().decode('utf-8')
    json_data = json.loads(data)
    for data in json_data:
        topics.append(data["organisation"] + '/bitgear/IO-Air')
```

Which leaves `topics` containing:

```
['port_36/bitgear/IO-Air', 'hchjffsd2immvavb7jiqtedp/bitgear/IO-Air']
```

You can then iterate through each of the topics in the topics list.

Answer (score 0):

Change this part of you code:

```
for orgs in org:
    TOPIC = orgs + '/bitgear/IO-Air'
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at you code, I think a much cleaner code would be to first convert your whole json to dataframe with all the columns using:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(json_data)
```

This will give you a dataframe with all the required fields and then you can simply append a string to all the column values of "organisation" column as below:

```
df['organisation'] = df['col'].astype(str) + '/bitgear/IO-Air'
```

To get this column values as list, you can simply use .tolist function as below:

```
df['organisation'].tolist()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for uuid_index, uuid in list(enumerate(uuid_list)):
```

try this in the first line of your code snippet. This will create a list object of elements with two items the index and the uuid which seems to be what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

First of all `org = dframe.values.tolist()` returns a list to which you can iterate but not call using `()`. So, `for` loop should be `for orgs in org:`.

Other thing I noticed is the following:

```
for orgs in org():
    TOPIC = org[orgs] + '/bitgear/IO-Air'
```

When iterate over a list you get values directly not indices, so you can't do `org[orgs]` in your case, orgs is the element in the list itself.

On the other hand, if you want index you can do `for idx, value in enumerate(org):`